# The screen comes out from behind

Tags: swift, xcode

I don't know why this is happening, already I have a similar functions on the project and this isn't happening.

When I delete the account and I to the previous screen or if the user is on background and open it again the 2 methods below cause you to be sent to the main screen but I detected this problem (in the picture)

There is the function when I go to the home when I delete the account

```
private func goToHomeWithLogin(){
   
    
    let home = HomeAssembly.presenterView()
    Utils.getTopViewController()?.present(home, animated: true)
```

And the getTopViewController do this:

```
func getTopViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    
    if let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        if let modal = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
            return modal
        } else if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            return navigationController
        }
    }
    
    return nil
    
}
```

[When I drag down the screen comes out from behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olE4S.gif)

Comment: looks like default card style of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present if you want it full screen (without the swipe down feature) try `home.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`before presenting it

Comment: FYI: .fullScreen also implies that you find another way to dismiss the home UIViewController

Comment: @DanielMarx Yeah, thank you. It worked, I forget to put it.

Comment: Do not modify your question to include the answer. If someone gave you the right answer, _accept_ their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like default card style of [UIViewController.present(...)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) if you want it full screen (without the swipe down feature) try home.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen before presenting it

```swift
let home = HomeAssembly.presenterView()
home.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
Utils.getTopViewController()?.present(home, animated: true)
```

Comment: Do not say "see comment". Comments are volatile; yours could vanish at any time, and besides, no one wants to cross-reference for information. If you have an explanation, put it into the answer itself so that it remains for others to enjoy.

Comment: will never happen again :)